# Populating navigation items from array in Nunjucks

Tags: arrays, json, templating, nunjucks

I need to populate breadcrumb navigation with the data I defined inside `set breadcrumb`. So, my code looks like this:

Breadcrumb items:

```
{% set breadcrumb = [{ name : 'Item name 1'}, { name : 'Item name 2'}, { name : 'Item name 3'}] %}
```

And the loop looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        {% for item in breadcrumb %}
        <li>
            <span>{{name}}</span>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But, the output is half-working. I get the `<li>` elements, but no Name. Just empty `<span>`.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span></span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Something with `{{name}}` is not ok, but I don't understand what.

Answer (score 0):

I managed it to solve the problem. 
The problem was, as I previously mentioned, in `{{name}}` part, witch, in provided example should be `{{item.name}}`